# Cant send message using directlineapi in bot framework

Tags: rest, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am using directline api for webchat.

After generating token, Along with that token in the header and activity object in the body I am requesting to this url:

https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/{conversationID}/activities

I am getting 404 page not found response:

Here is my Activity object:

> {"type":"message","text":"Testing Directline
>   API","conversation":{"id":"conversationId"},"recipient":{"id":"User request id"},"from":{"id":"mybot id","name":"My Bot Name
>   "}}

My Request body:

> {"type":"conversationUpdate","id":"ID","timestamp":"2017-12-23T05:03:45.5925924Z","serviceUrl":"https://directline.botframework.com/","channelId":"webchat","from":{"id":"FROMID"},"conversation":{"id":"conversationid"},"recipient":{"id":"mybotid","name":"Bot
>   Name"},"membersAdded":[{"id":"mybotid","name":"Bot name"}]}

I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

> getting 404 page not found response

If you’d like to send an activity to the bot, [the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-send-activity) that you are using seems ok.

```
POST https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/{conversationID}/activities
```

Based on my test, I suspect something wrong with `{conversationID}` that you provided, which causes the issue. Please try to [open a new conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-start-conversation) and use the returned conversation id to send activity and check if it works fine.

In my test, if I provide an incorrect conversation id, I will get **404** with “**Unknown conversation**” error message in fiddler.

[image]