# Does Azure Bot Service SDK require restify? (node)

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am attempting to transfer my v3 Azure Bot Service (`npm botbuilder`) to v4, however all tutorials or documentation seem to include `restify`, whereas v3 did not.

Is this a strict requirement? Or does have anyone have any examples without `restify`?

If so, does anyone know why it is required?

I am currently attempting to work on proactive messages from an azure function app.

V3:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

V4:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is not required to use `restify` or `express` in Bot Framework SDK v4. Any webserver framework that uses a similar `WebRequest` and `WebResponse` object is compatible with the Bot Framework.

Azure Functions could be used without any modifications. You create a `httpTrigger` listening to POST requests. Within the httpTrigger, you call the `adapter.processActivity` just like you would do in a 'normal' bot.

```js
const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {

    adapter.processActivity(req as any, context.res as any, async (context) => {
        // Route to main dialog.
        await myBot.run(context);
    });

};
```

*Currently you have to cast the WebRequest object as `any` while using Typescript and Azure Functions (or create a shim layer), but this will be solved in 4.9 according to [this open pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/pull/1899).*

In order to send proactive notifications, you don't even need this approach. I created an example for a proactive function for Bot Framework SDK v4 in [your similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658483/sending-proactive-messages-from-azure-functions-to-botservice-node).

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-overview?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) for v3, it is stated as below:

> The conversational logic for your bot is hosted as a web service. The Bot Framework SDK uses [restify](http://restify.com/), a popular framework for building web services, to create the bot's web server. The SDK is also compatible with [Express](http://expressjs.com/) and the use of other web app frameworks is possible with some adaption.

Also, for the proactive messages from an azure functions app, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55815818/how-to-send-proactive-notification-broadcast-message-using-azure-functions-to-u) Stack Overflow question which has the binding information for the azure function which will be triggered after every x minute.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer so that it helps others as well? Thanks