# Sending Proactive Messages from Azure functions to botservice - node

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-function-app

I am using botframework v4, but coming over from v3, I have not found any documentation that is similar to the code I use below but for v4, regarding sending proactive messages from Azure Function App

Below is the code I previously used but am having trouble adapting:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');

// setup bot credentials
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
  appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
  appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    if (req.body) {
        var savedAddress = req.body.channelAddress;
        var inMemoryStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage();
        var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector).set('storage', inMemoryStorage); 
        sendProactiveMessage(savedAddress, bot)
    }
};

function sendProactiveMessage(address, bot) {
    var msg = new builder.Message().address(address);
    msg.textLocale('en-US');
    var img = {
        attachments: [{
            contentType: "image/jpg",
            contentUrl: latestUrl,
        }]
    };
    msg.addAttachment(img.attachments[0]);
    msg.text('hello');
    bot.send(msg);
}
```

This works fine with v3 but not v4.

If possible I would also like to find a way to log a user out:

```
await botAdapter.signOutUser(innerDc.context, this.connectionName);
```

This is how I do it in the bot itself, but doing so from Azure Functions again is proving difficult.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great that you are making the move from v3 to v4! Have you had a look at [Send proactive notifications to users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript)? This example is pretty straight forward and can be used within an Azure function.

First you retrieve the Conversation Reference in your bot by calling `TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);`. This is the reference you could use in your proactive function to open the conversation. In your case you provide that via the request body to a proactive function, so I will do the same in my example.

My proactive endpoint example is written in Typescript, however it works the same way in plain Javascript. Create a HTTP trigger in Azure Functions and use the following code. I have added comments inline for clarity.

```js
const { BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder');

// Create adapter.
// If you need to share this adapter in multiple functions, you could
// instantiate it somewhere else and import it in every function.
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

module.exports = async function (context, req) {

    // Validate if request has a body
    if (!req.body) {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a conversation reference in the request body"
        };
        return;
    }

    // Retrieve conversation reference from POST body
    const conversationReference = req.body;

    // Open the conversation and retrieve a TurnContext
    await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {

         // Send a text activity
         // Depending on the channel, you might need to use  https://aka.ms/BotTrustServiceUrl

         await turnContext.sendActivity('Proactive hello');

    });

    context.res = {
        body: 'Message sent!'
    };

};
```

In the end you could make a request to this Azure Function, where you pass the Conversation Reference as body of the type `application/json`.

Extending this example with features like signOutUser is simple. You can call all functions within the `continueConversation` function, just as in a normal bot. You can even receive the adapter object there if you wish.

```js
await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
    // Sign user out
    turnContext.adapter.signOutUser(turnContext, 'connection-name');
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, is this going to work in an Azure Function App when it specifies Node? Is it possible to translate it to node please?

Comment: @JDT, I have changed my examples to plain Javascript which you could use in Azure Functions. Just make sure you have the `botbuilder` dependency installed.

Comment: Thank you for the translation! I am currently getting `at new RestError (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:1397:28)
` with this code - it fails at the sendActivity stage.

Comment: Which version of `botbuilder` have you installed? Could you possibly share your full package.json.

Comment: The solution above requires `const BotConnector = require("botframework-connector");
const credentials = new BotConnector.MicrosoftAppCredentials(
  process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
  process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
);
BotConnector.MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(
  conversationReference.serviceUrl
);` then it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having an issue with the signout feature however. The function seems to work - no errors are thrown. But it doesn't seem to have an effect on the bot itself. Are there additional functions/actions required to log the user out similar to `logoutDialog.js`  from the sample? (https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/18.bot-authentication/dialogs/logoutDialog.js)

Comment: @JDT, what do you want to accomplish? Do you just want to sign out / remove the users tokens from the Bot Service Auth service, or do you also want to clear the dialog stack?

Comment: Ok, so it seems the issue is with the fact I was putting the connectionName in as a string "this_connection_string" vs process.env.connectionName - it works now. Thanks again.

Comment: Similar to the original question, I assume attachments/images/videos can be sent like this too? As a separate note, is it possible to also `beginDialog` to choose certain dialogs/waterfalls using the proactive message method?

Comment: @JDT, you can do everything you would like within the proactive message method. You have access to the `TurnContext` within the method, the same context as in your normal bot.

Comment: @Mick can you show how this would look like for @azure/functions > v4.0.0 with InvocationContext?